# How to solve a simple equation with explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions, cubics

I'm currently struggling to solve a simple equation because I'm rusty on my algebra skills. I made [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734336/how-to-define-an-inverse-gamma-distribution-with-a-fixed-mode-but-a-changeable-v) the other day which helped me greatly. That equation that @StubbornAtom helped me with worked but I'm afraid I misread their advice and am coming back to it now. In this equation I need to solve for $\alpha$ but am so rusty with cubic equations I can't figure it out. Can you please help and provide a step by step? In grad school I'll be sure to take refresher algebra courses. Thanks!

$$\sigma^2(4) = \frac{Mode^2(\alpha + 1)^2}{(\alpha - 1)^2(\alpha - 2)}$$

Comment: Why do you call that a *simple* equation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the fraction you have a fourth degree polynomial equation in $\alpha$.  There is a formula for that which you can find if you search for quartic equation.  It is complex enough that most people either feed it to [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) or use numerical techniques to find an approximate answer.  In the post you link the $\alpha-2$ term is not squared.  That gives a cubic instead of a quartic.  The algebraic solution is not as complicated, but still enough of a mess that many people use numerics.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an insight on the number and positions of the real roots. This is a plot of

$$\frac{(\alpha+1)^2}{(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha-2)}.$$

The intersection with an horizontal give you from one to three solutions.

[image]

Caution: there are two additional extrema in the negatives (solve $9+5\alpha-5\alpha^2-\alpha^3=0$).